# change suffix and prefix to billions of files in a directory

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk, sed

i have billions of files in a directory, that they all have names like below:

```
split-00342964
split-00342965    
split-00342966
split-00342967
```

I would like

1. to remove prefix split-00
2. add to all files, the extension .png.

I have tried with

```
rename 's/^split-00//' split-00*
```

but i get `bash: /usr/bin/rename: Argument list too long`

as a result.

I am looking at a solution, that would also scale, which means it will take the least time, to make the above renaming tasks.

Comment: You can get around the "Argument list too long" by looping, e.g. `for f in *; do rename 's/^split-00//' $f; done`

Comment: the command you tried will only remove the prefix, won't add extension... I think find + rename might work best... try `find -type f -name 'split-00*' -exec rename -n 's/split-00(.*)/$1.png/' {} +` ... `-n` option is for dry run, so try with few files first.. and if you need to add extension regardless of filename with `split-00`, try `s/(?:split-00)?(.*)/$1.png/`

Comment: i would like to also try the sed command posted here, but was deleted immediately

Answer (score 1):

You may use the following command to achieve that,

```
for f in split-00*; do 
    mv $f $(echo $f|awk '{print substr($0,9) ".png"}'); 
done
```